# Recovering POST checkbox values in an array

Tags: php

Somewhat new to php, I did some searching but didn't find a clear answer. I have a page with automatically generated checkboxes coming from a read CSV file:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        echo '<tr><td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="included" value="col' . $row . '" /></td></tr>';
        echo "<br>";
        }
```

This form will submit to a page, and I want to get an array of the checked boxes, like "col2" "col4" "col5"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the name of your checkbox to **included[]**.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $row++;
  echo '<tr><td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="included[]" value="col' . $row . '" /></td></tr>';
  echo "<br>";
}
```

And then read the checked list with `$_POST['included']` (which will be an array).

Answer (score 1):

Name your inputs `included[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `name` to `name="included[]"` and you will get an array when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name from `included` to `included[]`